# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "...так что объяснять(,) кто я и зачем пришёл – не пришлось"?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое называется? Как это потом гуглить и искать у Розенталя (на будущее)? Нашла что-то похожее, но всё равно не разобралась, как это применить в моём случае.

Я тут перечитала это через время и подумала, может и вовсе так надо было: "...так что объяснять, кто я и зачем пришёл, не пришлось"?

Comment: Тире там точно не нужно. Оборот "кто" с двух сторон обособляется запятой. Причин для постановки тире вместо или помимо запятой нет.

Comment: То есть то, что я ниже написала верно?

Comment: Да, именно так. :)

Comment: Артём Луговой, вот на ваш ответ я и рассчитывала, вы обычно очень оперативно всем отвечаете. А вы, как обычно, сначала править спешите)

Comment: Спасибо за доверие, Юлия, приятно.) Просто уже сказать нечего: и вы рассудили потом правильно, и Третий глаз тоже всё объяснил. Я насчёт тире не очень хорошо разбираюсь, но мне почему-то кажется, что авторское интонационное тире всё же возможно, но совсем не обязательно. Запятой, однако, оно не поглотит.

Comment: Я очень люблю тире) И все авторские стараюсь оставить (не мои, я не автор), они придают какую-то резкость что ли... Но порой сама запутываюсь и в некоторых случаях (как этот) предпочитаю заменить на запятые. Вам спасибо большое и просьба глянуть мой следующий вопрос (простите, что наглею :))

Comment: "Заменить на запятые" — неправильная формулировка. Запятые **в любом случае нужны.** Верно говорить о возможном дополнении к запятым.

Comment: Вы правы, я неверно выразилась. Я имела в виду ситуации с тире в целом, не конкретно эту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна. Это называется - придаточная часть внутри главной.
*...так что объяснять, кто [есть] я и зачем [я] пришёл, не пришлось.* || "Кто я" и "зачем пришёл" - два однородных придаточных, которые относятся к главному предложению. Вследствие этого запятая между ними не ставится.

Примечание: запятая перед словом "кто" может не ставится, если перед ним стоит частица или союз.

Comment: Придаточная часть. Спасибо большое, что ответили на вопрос о том, как это называется.

Comment: "Часть" - это немного условно. Более официально - два однородных придаточных предложения внутри главного.